# Resting Hystrix from integration test

Tags: hystrix, spring-boot-test

I am trying to write an integrations tests for an rest service "A" with restAssured and SpringBootTest , and the A service is calling an other Service "B" in an Hystrix command , I would like to reset hystix after each test from my test

I tryed `Hystrix.reset();` and `HystrixPlugins.reset();` but it doesnt work, I guess that this mehods have to be called fome the app code not from the test